# Recycler view Scrolling issue

Tags: android

I am doing a program where I have recyclerview with different options(Options 1,2,3,4,5) that are loaded from web and then displayed in my first activity and when I click on one of the options app goes to second activity.I declared first activity as parent of second activity. So that I can go back from second activity onto first activity by clicking back arrow.
My problem is that when i first open my app recyclerview is displayed correctly
(Options 1,2,3,4,5). But if I click on one of the options and go to second activity and come back to first activity recyclerview is shown one below the other i.e. twice. (Options 1,2,3,4,5, 1,2,3,4,5)
Same thing also happens if I change orientation of my device while on my recyclerview activity.
Thanks

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Hi Brien, Did you not understand the question? In essence the question is recyclerview is getting displayed twice one after the other when I cange orientation or come back from second activity by pressing back button. So expected is Options 1,2,3,4,5 one below other. But recyclerview shows 1,2,3,4,5 and once again 1,2,3,4,5 one below the other. Thanks

Comment: IT SEEMS LIKE there is something wrong with the way you are providing data to your Recycler's adapter! (this can be the cause of data structure you are using to put data into the adapter) please share the code snippet where you are filling the adapter with data and attaching it to the recycler view.

Comment: "come back to first activity recyclerview is shown one below the other i.e. twice. (Options 1,2,3,4,5, 1,2,3,4,5) Same thing also happens if I change orientation"   Can you post the codes... eapecially onResume

Comment: Hi Rizwan, thanks for your answer. The reason I did not include a code snippet is because I was unsure about what to put, because I'm still working on project and the code is kind of messed up and all over the place with comments and TODOs here and there. I am creating recyclerview in onCreate method of my first activity and orientation change might cause problem as it must be getting created twice? It's more like one recyclerview getting appended to second one :)